# Mathematica dsolve fails unless I set the differential function first

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I start Mathematica and load a notebook with the following:

```
DSolve[{p'[t] == p[t], p[0] == {x0, y0}},  p[t], t]
```

When I evaluate that, Mathematica fails to solve and returns:

```
DSolve: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.
```

I then type in a line of code that sets p[t], so that the notebook contains:

```
p[t_] = {x[t], y[t]};
DSolve[{p'[t] == p[t], p[0] == {x0, y0}},  p[t], t]
```

When I evaluate that, Mathematica returns a solution:

```
{{x[t] -> E^t x0, y[t] -> E^t y0}}
```

If I then erase the line `p[t] = {x[t],y[t]}` so the code is back in its original state, then Mathematica (weirdly!) still returns a solution. But then when I restart Mathematica and repeat the above steps, it goes back to failing to solve the equation.

I'm using Mathematica 11.2. Am I doing something wrong in the above code?

Comment: To format code blocks and similar things, select the text in the question editor with your mouse and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Mathematica, perhaps like your web browser, keeps a cache of history. Just because you removed the line `p[t] = {x[t],y[t]}` doesn't mean Mathematica has forgotten that definition. You might be able to see that the old definition remains by evaluating `?p`.  You can erase the cache by restarting Mathematica. You can erase just the information about p with `p[t_] = .` You can confirm it is gone with another `?p` You might consider writing your `p` function as either having a list of two arguments consistently or having one argument consistently and see if that helps.

Comment: You should see Mathematica as an interactive program. If you typed ones `a=5` it will remember that `a` equals `5` until you re-declare it or `Clear` the variable to remove all its values and definitions. Or you resetart the Kernel, which is equivalent to restarting a program. So when you remove the line `p[t]={x[t],y[t]}` you did not remove it from Mathematica's memory. So it still knows its definition. If you write `Clear[p]` Mathematica will have a clear form of amnesia for the variable `p`